# What does a CNAME record do?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

If I host my DNS at a hosting company, and use them for email, is it possible for me to actually run the website at another hosting company?

I.e., the other hosting company does not provide access to DNS or an email server, so I just want to use them for Windows/[IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) and my other host for DNS and email.

Could I just create a CNAME record at host #1 pointing to host #2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. It doesn't matter who you host your DNS with; there are even free providers that will host it for you. At this point whether you need CNAME or A records is dependent on the server addresses the company gives you.

Let’s assume your email host provides you a server with the IP address of 20.20.20.20 and your webhost provides you with a website address of mysite.somehost.com and not a specific IP address.

In your DNS settings you will configure:

- mail.yourdomain.com with an A record pointing to 20.20.20.20.
- yourdomain.com and [www.yourdomain.com](http://www.yourdomain.com) with a CNAME record pointing to mysite.somehost.com.

**More information:** [Canonical Name Record (CNAME)](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/cname.html) showing the usage of CNAME records as aliases for a single IP address and for usage with external servers.

Answer (score 1):

Before we get into a flame war about CNAME records or [A records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types#Resource_records) and such, let’s establish one thing first.
Your DNS is hosted at a hosting company, and they also provide you with email.

So this means that your [MX record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) points to your hosting company's server.

If you get hosting for a website, then all you'll need to do is update the DNS with your hosting provider to point to the hosting providers server.

Think of a CNAME record as an alias. It doesn't point to an IP address, but another hostname.

Answer (score 0):

DNS doesn't tie you to a particular provider.

Your email hosting company should be able to give you the DNS settings that you need to use their service, and it shouldn't be a big deal. You may or may not need a CNAME record.

Answer (score -1):

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record):

> A CNAME record or Canonical Name
> record is a type of resource record in
> the Domain Name System (DNS) that
> specifies that the domain name is an
> alias of another, canonical domain
> name. This helps when running multiple
> services (like an FTP and a webserver;
> each running on different ports) from
> a single IP address. Each service can
> then have its own entry in DNS (like
> ftp.example.com. and
> www.example.com.). Network
> administrators also use CNAMEs when
> running multiple HTTP servers on the
> same port, with different names, on
> the same physical host.

So I think the answer to your question is **no**, as a CNAME record is used to use the same physical host to serve sites with different names. You want (if I understand correctly) to use two different physical hosts to serve the same name (but different protocols).

Comment: DV as I believe your answer is incorrect.